# как привести 2 последних символа toUpperCase и 2 первых toLowerCase в строке в Java?

Tags: java-8

"HЕllo world" -> "hello worLD"

Comment: Например, при помощи метода String.toCharArray() - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("HEllo world");
builder.setCharAt(0,
        Character.toLowerCase(builder.charAt(0)));
builder.setCharAt(1,
        Character.toLowerCase(builder.charAt(1)));
builder.setCharAt(builder.length() - 1,
        Character.toUpperCase(builder.charAt(builder.length() - 1)));
builder.setCharAt(builder.length() - 2,
        Character.toUpperCase(builder.charAt(builder.length() - 2)));
String result = builder.toString();
```